# using content-length when downloading a file using WCF Rest?

Tags: wcf, rest

We are developing an application for Web. Inside that application, to download a file, I have created a WCF Rest service that will download the files based on this link [Download using WCF Rest](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/797979/Uploading-Downloading-a-file-using-WCF-REST-servic). The purpose is to check for user authentication before downloading. I used streaming concept to download the file. It is now that I have found out few things

When the user downloads the file, he is not able to determine what are the file size and the time remaining. I analyzed and found out that the reason is because, it’s using the “**Transfer Encoding: chunked**” in the header so that the file will be downloaded in chunks. One of the advantages is that the memory consumption is less in the server even when there are many users downloading a file. So I thought of adding “**Content-Length**” header, but I found out that you can use only either one of the headers not both. So I was thinking how Hotmail and Gmail were downloading attachments. From my investigation, I found out that Hotmail uses chunking header whereas Gmail uses Content-length header. Also in the case of Gmail, it is also checking if the session is active or not then downloads the file accordingly. I want to achieve the following

a)  Like Gmail, I want to check if the session is active or not and then downloads the files accordingly. What will be the method for me to implement it?

b)  When downloading the file, I want to use **Content-Length** header instead of **Chunked** header. Also the memory consumption should be less. Can we achieve it in WCF Rest? If so how?

c)  Is it possible for me to add a header in WCF that will display the file size in the browser Downloads window?

d)  When downloading an inline images from WCF, I found out that the image after loading is not cached in local machine. I was thinking that once an image is shown in an HTML page, it will get automatically cached and the next time user visits the page, the image will load from cache instead from server. I want to cache the inline images to cache, what is the option that I can use for it? Are there any headers that I need to specify when downloading an inline image from server?

e)  When I download a zip file using WCF in IPhone Chrome browser, it’s not downloading at all. But the same link works in Android Chrome browser. What could be the problem? Am I missing header in WCF?

Are there any methods that will achieve the above?

Regards,
Jollyguy